# How to launch my Qt Installer in silent mode? (Qt Installer Framework)

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I generated an installer with Qt Framework Installer and I would like to know how to run my installer in silent mode?

I tried this commande line "myinstaller.exe -platform minimal" like this link (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTIFW-317)

but I have this error : "Unknown option: p, l, a, t, f, o, r, m"

I used the last Qt Framework Installer : 2.0.5

Comment: try --platform instead of -platform

Comment: I have  an "Unknown option: platform" when I use --platform

Answer (score 0):

QT Installation Framework doesn't provide any flavor of Silent installation.

One thing you can do is to provide a command line argument like

> isSilent=true

Then you can get this value in Controller script as below

> var isSilent = installer.value('isSilent ');

Now on the basis of this flag you can programmatically click next button of each Installation step of Installation Wizard.